# How to convert windows 64 bit timestamp to datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

I need to convert a windows hex 64 bit (big endian) date time to something readable in c#?

example `'01cb17701e9c885a'`

converts to `"Tue, 29 June 2010 09:47:42 UTC"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the big endian date time represent? Is it milliseconds since epoch?

Comment: For example, 02800008FFFFFFFF(String) is windows 64-bit timestamp structure, i want change this to datetime ex)2015-11-08

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to parse this to `long` as hexadecimal and use [`FromFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx) to generate windows file time as a local and use [`ToUniversalTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) to generate UTC equivalent.

```
long number = long.Parse("01cb17701e9c885a", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
DateTime date = DateTime.FromFileTime(number).ToUniversalTime(); // 06/29/2010 09:47:42
```

or simpler, use [`FromFileTimeUtc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc.aspx) as Matt mentioned;

```
DateTime date = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(number); // 06/29/2010 09:47:42
```

If you wanna get it as a string representation, you can use `ToString` method *that* `DateTime` instance with *english-based* culture (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)) as;

```
string str = date.ToString("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'UTC'", 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `FromFileTimeUtc` is easier, and more direct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc 
For detail, visit [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc(v=vs.110).aspx!)